# two way data bind using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

We need to bind such like two way binding . When i change value at also display value in content using Javascript or Jquery..

```js
function myFunction() {
  var val = '';
  val = document.getElementById("text1").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + val;
}
```

```html
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>
<input type='text' id="text1" onKeyup="myFunction()">

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

If you any idea then help me !!! Thank you in advance

Comment: have you heard about `KnockoutJS` or `AngularJS`? Those are better options for your case

Comment: where is `mySelect` id?

Comment: Your code is working what is wrong here?

Comment: @Paritosh Thanks for Give me suggestion but, i need in jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than appending the value of `demo` you should just be replacing the value with the value in the textbox.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text1").value;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/03gkm4wh/

---

Also:

`onKeyup` attribute should be lowercase - `onkeyup`.

`mySelect` isn't referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var val = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter data:</p>
<input type='text' id="text1" onKeyup="myFunction()">

<p>When you input new data, a function is triggered which updates the HTML.</p>

HTML Output:
<hr>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You should explain what was wrong with the original code, and how you fixed it.